# When exactly does the RDO tutorial end?

Tags: red-dead-online

I have claimed the Twitch Prime loot for Red Dead Online and it says that the content is available after finishing the tutorial.

Where exactly does the tutorial end?

Answer (score 1):

According to [gamefaqs](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/200179-red-dead-redemption-2/77147448) and [rdr2 site](https://www.rdr2.org/forums/topic/4305-stuck-on-the-online-tutorial/) the online tutorial ends after finishing a mission involving a horse, in chapter 2.